# Python scriptto test a DLL's functionality by importing it

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, ctypes

I have a DLL to calculate roots of quadratic equations. It has 4 APIs, 3 of which are for setting the coefficients of the quadratic equation ax^2 + bx + c, and one to get the roots, i.e.:

```
void setA(const double a);
void setB(const double b);
void setC(const double C);
int getSolution(double *x, double *y);
```

My Python script below uses ctypes to load and test the DLL. It isn't working. I am getting strange output for `x` and `y`. The result of `getSolution` should be 0, but I am getting 1 which implies coefficient `A` is 0.

```
from ctypes import *

# give location of dll
mydll = cdll.LoadLibrary("C:\\quadratic.dll")

mydll.setA(2)
mydll.setB(0)
mydll.setC(-4)
x = c_float(0)
y = c_float(0)
result = mydll.getSolution(byref(x), byref(y))
print(result)
print(x)
print(y)
```

I get the following output:

```
C:\>"C:\WINDOWS\py.exe" test.py    
1
c_float(0.0)
c_float(0.0)
```

Please suggest where I am going wrong and also alternatives to this method for testing DLLs.

Comment: The Windows directory should be on your PATH, plus the .py file extension should be associated with py.exe. So you should be able to execute `test.py` directly. You can add a shebang such as `#!python3` to the first line to ensure it runs in 3.x, assuming you have other versions installed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prototype the functions for ctypes to pass the correct arguments. It defaults to passing integers as C `int`.

```
from ctypes import *

mydll = CDLL("C:\\quadratic.dll")

mydll.setA.restype = None
mydll.setA.argtypes = [c_double]
mydll.setB.restype = None
mydll.setB.argtypes = [c_double]
mydll.setC.restype = None
mydll.setC.argtypes = [c_double]
mydll.getSolution.argtypes = [POINTER(c_double), POINTER(c_double)]

mydll.setA(2.0)
mydll.setB(0.0)
mydll.setC(-4.0)
x = c_double()
y = c_double()
result = mydll.getSolution(byref(x), byref(y))
print(result)
print(x.value)
print(y.value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [cffi](https://cffi.readthedocs.org/en/release-0.8/), where you can simply copy the function prototypes:

```
from cffi import FFI

ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef('''
    void setA(const double a);
    void setB(const double b);
    void setC(const double C);
    int getSolution(double *x, double *y);
''')

lib = ffi.dlopen("c:/quadratic.dll")
lib.setA(2)
lib.setB(0)
lib.setC(-4)

x = ffi.new("double *")
y = ffi.new("double *")
result = lib.getSolution(x, y)
print(result, x[0], y[0])
```